# protecting a single .exe-file for downloading with htaccess and htpasswd?

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, htpasswd

I have this, and only this, in a .htaccess file inside my downloads folder:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(exe)$">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Downloads"
  AuthUserFile path/to/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Once I click the link to download `a href="fileName.exe">FileName</a>`, I'm getting a 500 server error.

If I leave out the `<FilesMatch>`-part; The protection part is working, I guess, since I get the login box.
But once I get into the protected area, the 500 server error occurs.

What am I doing wrong here?

My intention was to protect only a single .exe file to prevent downloaded by anyone.

Is there any easier or more correct way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you didn't make a typo when asking firs line should be `<FilesMatch ~ "\.(exe)$">`
All info you can get from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0

Comment: Hey, didn't make a typo, so there might be a problem with the first line. Not on that computer until tomorow, so I'll look into it then...

Comment: Please point people at the current documentation - or at least to a version that's not 10 years old.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect a single file, why are you using FilesMatch to begin with ?

Of course, all Directory-level directives are prohibited inside htaccess files; your error log will tell you exactly what you did wrong.

Just use your httpd.conf with a straight  section.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm doing anything in this regards. Searching a bit, reading a bit and trying to learn a bit...  
But, don|t really know where I could find httpd.conf on my server or how to use it...  Do you have some links to some good informative information I could read?

Comment: httpd.conf has lots of practical info inside. It should be located in Linux in /etc/apache2/ or in Windows in installation_directory/etc or installation_directory/conf, where installation_directory is probably c:\Program files\Apache2